# PHP - Update command with DB mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've tried to do this, but I just can't find the error. It worked before where I just had "name, email, mobile" when I add "password" it stops working...

I don't know what to do for it to work properly as it worked before, please help

```
if ( !empty($_POST)) {
    // keep track validation errors
    $nameError = null;
    $emailError = null;
    $mobileError = null;
    $passwordError = null;
    // keep track post values
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $password = $_POST['mobile'];

    // validate input
    $valid = true;
    if (empty($name)) {
        $nameError = 'Please enter Name';
        $valid = false;
    }

    if (empty($email)) {
        $emailError = 'Please enter Email Address';
        $valid = false;
    }

    if (empty($mobile)) {
        $mobileError = 'Please enter Mobile Number';
        $valid = false;
    }

    if (empty($password)) {
        $passwordError = 'Please enter Password Number';
        $valid = false;
    }
    // update data
    if ($valid) {
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //ERROR IS HERE    $sql = "UPDATE customers  set name = ?, email = ?, mobile = ?, password =?, WHERE id = ?";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($name,$email,$mobile,$password,'ADD',$id));
        Database::disconnect();
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
} else {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers where id = ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($id));
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $name = $data['name'];
    $email = $data['email'];
    $mobile = $data['mobile'];
    $password = $data['password'];
    Database::disconnect();
}
```

?>

Comment: `password =?, WHERE id` remove the comma. Check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) when things fail to get more information on why things fail.

Comment: What does "work" mean? (i.e., what are you trying to do that is failing?) Also, what was the error you are seeing? Lastly, I'd recommend updating the formatting so all of your code is in a code block for readability (including the last `?>`).

Comment: aynber thanks a lot, it worked!!!!

Comment: Don't store plain text passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change `$password = $_POST['mobile']`;  to `$password = $_POST['password'];`

Comment: While this would cause bad data going into the database, it would not stop the update from working as the OP claims.

Answer (score 0):

Hi seems like you have a syntax error,

**unexpected comma**

```
//ERROR IS HERE    $sql = "UPDATE customers  set name = ?, email = ?, mobile = ?, password =?, WHERE id = ?";// remove comma prior to WHERE
```

try like below,

```
  $sql = "UPDATE customers  set name = ?, email = ?, mobile = ?, password =? WHERE id = ?";
```